# Principal Minor and Non-zero Eigen values in Diagonal Matrix

Tags: matrices, characteristics

While reading the definition of pseudo determinant in [here](http://www.people.ku.edu/~jlmartin/papers/pseudo.pdf), I've found the following :

> $$pdet(L) : = \sum_{I\in[n] , |I| = r}det(L_{I,\ I}) = \prod_{i=1}^r\lambda_i$$

where $L_{I,\ I}$ denotes the principal minor, which strikes out two same indexed rows and columns from the original matrix.

The author presented the second equation very trivially, but I can't prove the relationship between the sum of all principal minors and the mulitplication of eigenvalues.

Comment: This appears to be, up to sign, the $x^{n-r}$ coefficient of the
characteristic polynomial of $L$, which is the $r$-th elementary polynomial
in the eigenvalues.

Comment: And so (since all the other eigenvalues are $0$) only this term is non-zero in the $r$-th elementary polynomial.